# Highlight matching cells

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a macro that will automatically highlight any cells in the current worksheet if the value of those cells is the same as the currently selected cell. So if cell B2 is currently selected, and it contains the value 7, then all other cells with a value of 7 will be highlighted. This is for a 9x9 Grid for a Sudoku puzzle. **The Range is B2:J10**. Note: Blank cells are not to be selected and highlighted and if possible a way to disable if not used. There is a solution listed that is 10 years old but it highlights the entire worksheet for any numbers that match and if you click on a blank cell it highlights all 100 million blank cells (just a guess) and this is why I need the Range as mentioned.

Comment: Hello! SO is not a code-writing service. Please show what you have tried already and describe the error you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to write out a code for you, but some tips:

- use a `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` event to trigger when a new cell is selected
- use `Dim Cell as Range` and then `For each Cell in MySheet.Range("B2:J10")` loop to check all the cells in your relevant range
- basic if statement within the loop should do the trick; `If Cell.Value = Selection.Value Then`
- if you want the code to not trigger when a blank cell is selected, probably need to add that as an If statement right at the start - 'if selection is blank then `exit sub`' sort of thing.

That should be all the pointers you need - over to you to give it a try and work out specific details to suit you (what colour / style to highlight, etc).

Comment: Thanks, Spencer Barnes, but I haven't mastered the VBA coding just yet, I can read some and understand, but not all

Answer (score 1):

In the below code I'm simply using the conditional formatting to highlight all the cells with the value as light red. I've also added an If else statement to not highlight any cells when the selection is blank.

I would recommend you to go to the developer tab create a macro and assign some shortcut to it (Ctrl + Shift shortcut) so that you can easily invoke it everytime you select a cell. When you have created the macro copy this code and paste it in the VBA editor.

Also, if this solution works for you please select this as the accepted answer. Thanks!

```
Sub Final()
Dim var As Double
var = ActiveCell.Value

Range("B2:J10").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Delete

If var <> 0 Then
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:=var
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("B2").Select
Else
    Range("B2").Select
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Jay Mangal, I already have a similar program like this which is located outside of the Grid. I would like to be able to click on any number within the Grid that would highlight all corresponding numbers. Thanks, and it works fine. However, if I click on a blank cell it highlights the interior color of every cell, except B2,  to grey and when I click off the Grid they return to normal.

Comment: Hi jeh, that's very easy. While writing the if else I did not focus on that. Just do this, after the Else statement add the following code: Range("B2").Select

Comment: I've edited my code to add that. Try this code. It was not highlighting rather it was just selection of those cells.

Comment: Hi Jeh, if the above solution worked for you I would request you to please select it as the accepted answer and give a "up arrow". That would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for getting back on here, but looking for other solutions. This now works and will play around with it for any complications it might make. Thanks and will accept as an answer.

Comment: Yes this answered my question

Comment: Jan Mangal, I will be using the code you supplied, but not familiar with those color numbers you presented. Yours is a pink cell with a red number, I need those colors to be a yellow cell with a black number. Just give me the numbers and I will be able to update your code. Thanks

Comment: Jan Mangal, I finally used this in my puzzle. I removed the lines that had to do with the cell pattern & color. It was showing as pink, but  the puzzle I have there are many cells of different colors & your code changed  the cell color & this puzzle the only way to know where you are is the colors so I removed that part and changed the font color to vbRed. The current font is set at 24, but need to raise  that to 30 only on the numbers selected by your macro. I tried several ways to enter the font.size, but none would worked, so any help on that would be appreciated.